# "create-react-app" doesn't create any project

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use *ReactJS* for the first time, so I'm following the [official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment) but I can't create a new *React Project* using `create-react-app`.

It doesn't work, when I run it simply does "nothing", see following:

[image: terminal]

I've also tried with sudo privileges with no success.
Any suggestions, please?

**Note:** I'm on *Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon*

Thanks

### UPDATE

[image]

`sudo npm i -g create-react-app` works fine.

Comment: can you just execute this and share the result? `npx create-react-app --info`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, same result: nothing.

Comment: Ok, so usually your global packages are installed with your user's home directory on linux, can you just run `npm update` && `npm rebuild` and try again?

Comment: Both commands terminated very quickly and then anything was changed.

Comment: Did it work? if it still doesn't.. `npm i -g create-react-app` again

Comment: I've printed the output in the question, it works only with sudo.

Comment: That's absolutely fine.. In linux/macs you need to run all the global installations with`sudo`. can you try again with `create-react-app` again?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved upgrading *nodejs* and *npm* with the following commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

So, current versions are:

[image: result]

And now the `create-react-app` command works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of npm use yarn package manager it solves the problem.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/

To install it on Linux

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable

hope it solves your issue

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it `npx create-react-app <name>`?

https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: if `create-react-app` is installed globally, then you don't need to run it via `npx`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it does the same result.